# excel large function issues when having duplicate values

Tags: excel

ok so this must sound like a dumb question but i have a column with numbers and some numbers may contain duplicate numbers. Lets say column A has 20,20,10. When i do the large function for example =large(columnA,2) it will give me 20 instead of 10. How do I fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
=LARGE(IF(range < LARGE(range,2),range),1)
```

Entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter (If entered correctly, Excel will surround with curly braces {}). If you want 3rd, 4th, 5th... number, just change value in inner `large()`.

You can also try:

```
=LARGE(range,COUNTIF(range,MAX(range))+1)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to remove the duplicates from the output.